# iOS : Programmatically control the volume of Notification alert and sound theme

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have a requirement like, through the app we want to set the notification sound and volume. this is because of our requirement. There is a three different states - Happy, Sad and Normal. when user gain some points we will send congratulation message, when he lost some points we send that message also. promotion related some other message too. for all these state i want to set the different notification sound and volume too. Appreciate your inputs. Ty

Comment: Do you want it for local Notifications or Push Notification?

Comment: @JasmeetKaur, it's for Push Notification

Answer (score 1):

For Local Notification

```
func scheduleNotifications(inSeconds: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (_ Success: Bool) ->()){
        ...
        notif.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "CustomSound.mp3") 
        ...
}
```

For Push Notification

APS data should have sound key in it and your server need to send the file name which should be play,

```
{
  aps =
  {
    alert = "message";
    sound = "sound file name.extension";
    badge = 1;
  };
}
```

Comment: Can i have one static file in my project and use that for pushnotification?